# Sandbox Marketing Banner Blocked by Content Security Policy

Tags: login, iframe, content-security-policy

I was logging in to the sandbox today and I noticed that instead of the usual marketing banner I got an error message saying:

> Blocked by Content Security Policy
>
> This page has a content security policy that prevents it from being loaded in this way.
>
> Firefox Developer Edition prevented this page from loading in this way because the page has a content security policy that disallows it.

[image]

It seems that requests for this page aren't allowing it to be framed by `test.salesforce.com`:

[image]

Does anyone know who to contact about getting this fixed?

Comment: Unless you have premier support no one is listening. Even if you did do you have the time to spend getting it to the right people after providing steps to reproduce, screen shares, etc? I typically find waiting it out to be best use of my time. But if you do find a path that is relatively painless do share

Comment: @Eric Unfortunately I don't have access to premier support. I guess I'll have to try submitting a case and see how that goes this time.